# Path to executable added to PATH and executable runs using cmd but not from a python IDE

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, pycharm, spyder

I have an `.exe` under `%COPASIDIR%\bin` and this path has been added to the `PATH` variable. When I open `cmd` and type the name of the `exe` (`CopasiSE`) I get the expected behaviour, shown in the screen shot below:
[image]

Additionally, when I start `ipython` or `python` from the command prompt and run `os.system('CopasiSE')` I also the expected behaviour. However, when using an IDE (spyder and pycharm) the I get:

```
import os
os.system('CopasiSE')
Out[9]: 1
'CopasiSE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

**Edit**

Based on comments I tried using `subprocess.call` with the `shell=True` switch and got the following:

[image]

**Edit2**
After seeing @Arne's comment I compared the path that I get from `os.system('echo %PATH%')` command from the IDE (`path_ide`) to what I get directly from the shell (`path_cmd`) and the specific path pointing to the directory containing my `exe` is in both outputs.

Comment: Did you try using the `subprocess` module? I know it has a special `shell` attribute, which should solve your problem

Comment: Try os.system("echo %path%") from the IDEs

Comment: When you saytthe  "specific path pointing to my exe" is in `PATH`, you mean the directory that has the executable, right? Only directories get added to `PATH`.

Comment: Yes this is what I mean.I'll make it clearer in the question